# Bigquery parallel reads and writes at the same time

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know whether bigquery supports whether reads and writes happening on the same table at the same time.

FOr example in Hive we cannot do that and results zero rows will be fetched incase writes happening on the table while reading. Does Bigquery also follows the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a mental model like, at the time of query, BigQuery takes a snapshot of all the tables needed for the query and work on the snapshot of data.

There can be parallel writing to table(s) but has no impact on the reading query.